# Remove everything in every line after/before the mentioned text using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to remove everything in every line after/before the mentioned text. In the following code, I want when the "Remove After!" button is pressed then in every line text after mentioned text "love" must be removed. When the "Remove Before!" button is pressed then in every line text before mentioned text "love" must be removed.

**Example**:

I love donuts! --> Remove After! --> "I love"

I love donuts! --> Remove Before! --> "love donuts!"

Note I want this for every line. I have no idea about how I can do this so I am just giving scratch code!

**Code:**

```js
function afterFun() {
  var rAfter = document.getElementById("iAfter").value;
  document.getElementById("TextInput").value = document.getElementById("TextInput").value.replace(rAfter, "");
}

function beforeFun() {
  var rBefore = document.getElementById("iBefore").value;
  document.getElementById("TextInput").value = document.getElementById("TextInput").value.replace(rBefore, "");
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="30" id="TextInput" rows="10" style="width: 100%;">I love donuts!</textarea><br><br>

<input value="love" type="text" id="iAfter"><br>
<input onclick="afterFun()" type="button" value="Remove After!" /><br /><br>

<input value="love" type="text" id="iBefore"><br>
<input onclick="beforeFun()" type="button" value="Remove Before!" /><br /><br>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing the same thing in both function, just changing the variables name. My approach would be to split the input string by the target word:

```
let result = str.split(target);
```

It would return an array of strings saved in the `result` variable, with the **beforeText** at index `[0]` and the **afterText** at index `[1]`;

Then, just get the index you want (depends on the button you clicked) and add the target before or after the result:

```js
function afterFun() {
  var target = document.getElementById("iBefore").value;
  var text = document.getElementById("TextInput").value;

  var lines = text.split("\n");   //split lines

  document.getElementById("TextInput").value = "";
  lines.map(line => {
      var result = line.split(target);
      document.getElementById("TextInput").value += result[0] + target + "\n";
  })
}

function beforeFun() {
  var target = document.getElementById("iBefore").value;
  var text = document.getElementById("TextInput").value;

  var lines = text.split("\n");   //split lines

  document.getElementById("TextInput").value = "";
  lines.map(line => {
      var result = line.split(target);
      document.getElementById("TextInput").value += target + result[1] + "\n";
  })
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="30" id="TextInput" rows="10" style="width: 100%;">I love donuts!</textarea><br><br>

<input value="love" type="text" id="iAfter"><br>
<input onclick="afterFun()" type="button" value="Remove After!" /><br /><br>

<input value="love" type="text" id="iBefore"><br>
<input onclick="beforeFun()" type="button" value="Remove Before!" /><br /><br>
```

Comment: I want to perform this on every line. Like I love donuts!<br>I love donuts! --> Remove After! --> "I love"<br> "I love". 2) I love donuts!<br>I love donuts! --> Remove Before! --> love donuts!<br>love donuts!

Comment: Look updated answer, just add another split to separate lines by "\n" chars